# Any coverage tool allows to ignore getters , setter, equals and hashcode?

Tags: java, unit-testing, code-coverage, cobertura

We are currently using Cobertura but i can't figure out a way to exclude those methods. I tried Emma and clover as well which i couldn't find any way to do as well.

Please , spare your "You should test those" comments , this is some kind of specific thing we want to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the latest version of Cobertura has a new annotation `@IgnoreMethod` that will accomplish exactly this for you (search for IgnoreMethodAnnotation in the page linked below).

http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/